# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run following script but I'm facing with this error:

> "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'"

```
X1 = []
Y1 = []
X2 = []
Y2 = []
X3 = []
Y3 = []
X4 = []
Y4 = []
X5 = []
Y5 = []

for b in range(1,5):
    v = "f%d" %(b)
    f = "/raw-data/data%d.dat" %(b)

for N in range(1,5):
    for i, line1 in enumerate(open(f, 'r')):
        if i >0:
            pass

        s1 = line1.split()
        "X%d" %(N).append(float(s1[0]))
        "Y%d" %(N).append(float(s1[1]))
```

Comment: Please, don't rollback useful edit

Comment: append is a method that works on lists, not on int-s... not sure what you're trying to do here

Comment: I need the script above to do "X1.append(float(s1[0]))" and also "X1.append(float(s1[0]))"  in the first and second cycles and continue by X3, X4 and X5.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what you want to do and what you are doing. You want to add float to integer instead of list. `N` is just a number, you have do `append` on one of your lists instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to append to given list number, but what You did won't work.
The best way would be to create map of lists and get them by index, like that:

```
lists = {
   1: {'x': [], 'y': []},
   2: {'x': [], 'y': []},
   3: {'x': [], 'y': []},
   4: {'x': [], 'y': []},
   5: {'x': [], 'y': []},
}

for b in range(1,5):
    v = "f%d" %(b)
    f = "/raw-data/data%d.dat" %(b)

for N in range(1,5):
    for i, line1 in enumerate(open(f, 'r')):
        if i >0:
            pass

        s1 = line1.split()
        lists[N]['x'].append(float(s1[0]))
        lists[N]['y'].append(float(s1[1]))
```