# How to print Fibonacci sequence

Tags: python

I am working on a Python tutorial. I am getting an incorrect result as I try to work through an example.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003792/attributeerror-int-object-has-no-attribute-append) does not answer my question.

I have defined my function like so:

```
def fibonaccci(sequence_length):
    "Return the Fibonacci sequene of length * sequence_length"
    sequence = [0,1]
    if sequence_length < 1:
        print("Fibonacci squence only defined fo length 1 or greater")
        return
    if 0 < sequence_length < 3:
        return sequence[:sequence_length]
    for i in range(2, sequence_length):
        sequence_length.append(sequence[i-1]+sequence[i-2])
    return sequence
```

Expected:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

Actual:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_35261/4107038898.py in <module>
----> 1 fibonaccci(int(12))

/tmp/ipykernel_35261/2532562687.py in fibonaccci(sequence_length)
      8         return sequence[:sequence_length]
      9     for i in range(2, sequence_length):
---> 10         sequence_length.append(sequence[i-1]+sequence[i-2])
     11     return sequence

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: `sequence_length` is not a list, but it is an integer. Therefore, you can't append anything to it. Why you don't create your own list?

Comment: hint: look at the representation of `sequence_length` in your IPython session. what type of variable is it?

Comment: You just confused `sequence_length` and `sequence`. The list `sequence` was created in order for new integers to be appended to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to append to the `int` parameter `sequence_length` instead of the length `sequence`. Just append to that instead:

```py
def fibonaccci(sequence_length):
    "Return the Fibonacci sequene of length sequence_length"
    sequence = [0, 1]
    if sequence_length < 1:
        print("Fibonacci squence only defined for length 1 or greater")
        return
    if 0 < sequence_length < 3:
        return sequence[:sequence_length]
    for i in range(2, sequence_length):
        sequence.append(sequence[i - 1] + sequence[i - 2])
    return sequence
```